# How can I hide connect to database URI

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, uri

I am started learn NodeJS and Mongodb and now I want to upload my project on GitHub, but don`t know how to hide link for connect to database. And should it be done?

`mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://howToHideThisInfo?:howToHideThisInfo?@cluster0.ta9wa.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the URI in a file and then add that file to `.gitignore` and you can use `process.env` variables, more on them here [Process.env](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env). You can pass the variables when starting the node app as `USER_ID=239482 USER_KEY=foobar node app.js` and update the code where you want to use them as `process.env.USER_ID`. So your URI code would look like so:

```
'mongodb+srv://'+process.env.NAME+':'+process.env.PASSWORD+'@cluster0.ta9wa.mongodb.net/database?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```